# Storing multiple values in $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session

I am new to php and this issue is bugging me sincelast one day. I have three pages,
**1. classpage.php** ---- which holds,

```
<?php
session_start();

class addStock{
    public function storeSessArray($stk_code){
         array_push($_SESSION['recentlyView'],$stk_code);
    }
}

?>
```

2. **logic.php**---which holds,

```
$_SESSION['recentlyView']=array();
$checkSession = new addStock;

$chkSession = $checkSession->storeSessArray($val);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and 
**3. front.php** which holds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
   $val='5';
?>
<?php
   include 'logic.php';
?>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to keep an array of values stored in `$_SESSION['recentlyView']` array when someone loads **front.php**. But each time I assign a different value to $val, only the last value which was stored in $val appears in `$_SESSION['recentlyView']` array. I want each of the value that was used in `$val` to be stored in `$_SESSION['recentlyView']`

Comment: Have you run `session_start()` at the beginning of each request?

Comment: I did started session with session_start().Sorry, I missed posting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you keep overwriting the session array. Try checking if it’s set already:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['recentlyView']))
    $_SESSION['recentlyView'] = array();
```

This will only set the array once, then your method will just add to it.

Also, as noted in the other answer, make sure to put the `session_start();` in the most top-level page at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should solve your problem.

class addStock{

```
public function storeSessArray($stk_code){

   $_SESSION['recentlyView'][] =$stk_code;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must call `session_start()` before there is any output.  The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#refsect1-function.session-start-notes) notes

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

As you've presented your code, the very first thing that is loaded is `front.php` which includes `logic.php` which calls the class in `classpage.php`.  (I don't see how that page is referenced-- whether it is by include or spl.

You've got the right idea in separating your presentation from the logic, but you've got the order backwards.  The very first thing that needs to happen is the execution and loading of relevant php code, with presentation being the very *last* thing that happens.
Unfortunately the very first things that happens in your script is it immediately starts output.

The solution is to funnel all requests through index.php (look up how to do seo-friendly urls), and from there use a "front controller" or "router".

Short of that, you need to include a brief php section on top of front.php, so that session start is called before output.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'logic.php'; // don't print anything from your logic; pass back a variable to print below.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. I a newbie and concept of "front controller" and router was new for me. I couldn't solve my problem(I didn't understand how to use this concept) with this but learned a bit about "routing", which I believe I would be using in future.

Comment: Once it clicks, you'll find it very useful.  Speaking of useful, don't forget to accept Rasclatt's answer since he caught the problem.  If any of the other answers were useful, feel free to upvote.